# Make search funtion in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make search that will get the result which we type in bar. like when i type "country" it should get result of this search.
I make a search function in controller and also create it's route and make a view file for it. I am sharing code of my work please help me where i am going wrong.God bless you. New in laravel.Thanks in advance.

```
//HERE IS MY VIEW FILE FOR SEARCH RESULT.
@extends('footer')
@extends('header')
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Search|Result 
        </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('public/css/style.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('public/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('public/js/jQuery.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('public/js/javascript.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>


<div class="container">
    @if(isset($user))
        <p> The Search results for your query <b></b> are :</p>
    <h2>Sample User details</h2>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($user as $value)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$value->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$value->email}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    @endif
</div>
 </body>
</html>

//HERE IS MY CONTROLLER CODE.

public function Search(Request $request)
        {

           $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
           $user = DB::table('student')->where('name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
           ->orWhere ( 'email', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->get();
           if(count($user) > 0)
           return view('search_result')->withDetails($user)->withQuery ( $q );
           else 
            return redirect()->route('std_view')->with('No Details found. Try to search again !');
        }

//HERE IS MY SEARCH BAR CODE 

<form action="search/result" method="get" role="search" class="form-inline">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm ml-3 w-75" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search"
    aria-label="Search">
 </form>

//HERE IS MY ROUTE

Route::get('search/result','StudInsertController@Search');
```

Comment: What problem are you having with your code ?

Comment: It's not showing result and not any error

Answer (score 0):

hey tell us what is your problem and you can use two thing for simplicity

1. in form method should be POST
2. in return you can use compact

   return view('search_result',compact('user', 'q') );

Comment: Brother It's not showing any result and not any error. I'm confused

Comment: Tanvir Ahmed bro thank you very much for your help i got my desire result. Thank you very much but "$q" throwing an error i used just 'q'. Like ==> return view('search_result', compact(array('user', 'q')) );

Comment: if you find help then please vote by clicking on arrow up sign, so that others can find helpful

Comment: if you find helpful because of my answers then vote so others can know that it is helpfull